# asp.net MVC: Clear the model state

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm looking at refactoring a razor view that isn't currently using the model to pass values to the corresponding controller.This view also contains a JS method thst clears the controls on the form.

```
  $('#btnClear').bind("click", ClearTheForm);
```

...

```
$('#txtContact).val('');    
 $('[name="radCommType"]').attr('checked', false);
```

Given that I'm now binding my input controls thus:

```
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactNumber, "contact number ")
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactNumber)
```

..What's the best practice way to clear them?

(I'll update this, based on the reply from Ehsan)

The purpose is simply to clear all the controls on the form..I don't want to "process" the current model in any way. The form is actually in a jQuery tab, and the model is loaded from the "parent" view, that of: Index()

```
//Create the model within Index()
 var commsModel = new CommunicationModel
        {
            CustCommsModel = custCommsModel,
            EngineerCommsModel = engineerCommsModel
        };

        return View(commsModel);
```

So, inside my child view, I believed that the following would work:

```
 $.ajax({ url: "/Communications/Index", type: "GET"});
```

It correctly calls the Index() action method, to which I've added  ModelState.Clear();  ie

```
ModelState.Clear();  
var commsModel = new CommunicationModel
        {
            CustCommsModel = custCommsModel,
            EngineerCommsModel = engineerCommsModel
        };

        return View(commsModel);
```

However, even though I can step through the code the textBox is still not cleared.

```
   @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ContactNumber, "contact number ")
   @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ContactNumber)
```

Any ideas?

Ta,

yogi

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume this form is going to make a POST / GET to a controller method that will process this form, and then reload the form or display errors etc etc...

The easiest thing you can do to accomplish your task is in your controller method that catches the form data and processes it, instead of returning the model you received back to the view, simply instantiate a new model and return that to your view. You also would need to clear the model `ViewState`

Your method might look something like this

```
public ActionResult ProcessForm(SomeModel Model)
{
    //process model

    var NewModel = new SomeModel();
    ModelState.Clear();
    return view(NewModel);
}
```

At this point, the form would be reloaded and all of the inputs would be cleared.